# Visual Studio 2010 random error

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Everytime I start visual studio 2010 I keep getting this error but it still opens and runs normally. I have reinstalled it many times but still the problem persists. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Error Message:
The product is not installed properly. Please reinstall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a little hard to help without more information.

Visual Studio has so many components, it is possible that you have not done a "full" reinstall, e.g. removed all components before installing again.

I would recommend you look in the event log or try to diagnose this a little bit further to see what the component actually is that is failing so you can address the exact issue.

Alternatively, this could actually be a problem with a third party component/VS addin which is failing to start with VS - and, by clicking OK, you progress without it - but, reinstalling VS won't fix it.

Again, without more information, it is really hard to help.

Comment: thanks for this, it turned out my Visual Assist X  add-in was not starting correctly. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

Try something like the [VS Uninstall utility](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/vs2010uninstall/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4321).  Microsoft has gotten better about releasing these tools to scrub their product out of your system (much more effectively than a regular uninstall).